# npm live-server this app can't run on your pc

Tags: windows-8.1, npm-live-server

I'm learning react, and  Installed live-server via npm globally. Each time i try to serve the directory (live-server public), i get a windows error saying - "this app can't run on your pc"[image]

I am using windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the problem was that live-server was trying to render my app using a browser but the default chrome browser was having issues so it kept popping that error.

The solution was just to set Firefox as my default browser from the control panel. Control Panel>default programs